# Systems of linear modular equations with unknowns in the moduli

Tags: algorithms, divisibility, diophantine-equations, computer-algebra-systems

I am interested in systems of linear modular equations, where the unknowns also appear in the moduli. The general form would be:

$A \vec{x}= \vec{b} \;\textrm{mod} \; (C \vec{x}+\vec{d})$

where A and C are constant integer matrices, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ are constant vectors in $\mathbb{Z}^d$ and $\vec{x}$ is the unknown vector in $\mathbb{Z}^d$.

In order for the mod to make sense, let us throw in some inequalities as well:

$C \vec{x}+\vec{d} > \vec{1}$ where $\vec{1}$ is the all one vector.

**Question:** Are these equations decidable? If yes, is there a bound known on the size of their solutions? If no, is there a reduction from Matiyasevich's theorem?

Comment: Well, a single modular equation with constant modulus $$ ax = b \mod c $$ can be rewritten as $$ ax = cy + b $$ for some $y\in\mathbb Z$. If you have $x$ in your modulus as well, this becomes $$ ax = (cx + d)y + b $$ which is an equation in $x$, $y$ and the mixed term $xy$. So it might be worthwhile to investigate the theory for quadratic systems of diophantine equations. I'm no expert there.

Comment: Yes, this is why I put the tag diophantine equations -- but the system we obtain has quite a special form and I do not see any obvious reduction to prove undecidability.